# Android memory error

Tags: android, file, http, memory

I cannot understand why this keeps crashing with a memory error:

```
    server = new URL("http://-link cannot be supplied-");
    BufferedReader reader2 = read(server);
    line = reader2.readLine();
    StringBuilder bigString = new StringBuilder("");
     while(line!=null) {
         bigString.append(line);
         reader2.readLine();
     }
```

the file is not -that- big 7000 odd lines @ 240,031  bytes on disk.

Basically what i need to do is to tell wether the file contains a small string (a postcode) the file is basically a list of postcodes.

What is the best way to read this in? as obviously what i am doing is not working at all :D

Comment: Please supply the details of the memory error and the output of logcat. It will help us diagnose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop never ends!

```
while(line!=null) {
     bigString.append(line);
     line = reader2.readLine();
 }
```

should work.

Comment: LOL! I am so embarrased i am just gonna go hang myself :D